# Print gridview by using PrintPageSize

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, printing

I would like to print a gridview, but according to the length of every row, I need to set the print page size on every page. For example, page1 prints 5 records, page2 prints 10 records. Is it possible to use  gridview.PrintPageSize to achieve it?

Comment: Refere [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20903/Printing-a-GridView-with-Paging)

Comment: @Rahul Hendawe I had read it many times but it seem no provide any solution for my question